i couldn't access camera...I tried using pip install opencv-python still not working
when i used pip install opencv-python in terminal i got this message
PS D:\VS Code\Python_pycharm\pythonProject> pip install opencv-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\lohia\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (4.10.0.84)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in c:\users\lohia\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (2.1.0)
PS D:\VS Code\Python_pycharm\pythonProject> 

and when i run the code later i got this error
Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\VS Code\Python_pycharm\pythonProject\venv\gs.py", line 1, in <module> import cv2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' 
i tried in pycharm, vs code, and google collab still I am not able to access camera...and fyi my camera works fine while vc and all

import cv2
import imutils
import datetime

gun_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

firstFrame = None
gun_exist = None

while true:
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width = 500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    gun = gun_cascade.detectMultiscale(gray,
                                       1.3,5,
                                       minSize = (100,100))
    if len(gun)> 0:
        gun_exist = True

    for (x, y, w, h) in gun:
        grame = cv2.rectangle(grame,
                              (x,y),
                              (x+w, y+h),
                              (255,0,0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y : y+h, x : x + w]
        roi_color = frame[y : y + h, x : x + w]

    if firstFrame is None:
        firstFrame = gray
        continue

    cv2.imshow("Security feed", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord('q'):
        break

if gun_exist:
    print("guns detected")
else:
    print("guns didn't detected")

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

this is my code
